# A strange message

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

Yesterday I helped my grandfather clean out his attic and amongst some old papers I found a peculiar message, that seemed strange to me. Upon asking my grandfather what this was about, he told me that he and a few of his friends founded a club of sorts and anyone that could figure out the pass phrase could join.

This was the message:

```
-..- ...- ...- .-.. . ..-. ... .-. . .- --- -.. 
-. . -.-- ... .--- -.- .-- .--. 
...- --. .--- .-- .--- ..- -..- .--- .-- - -.. 
.--- -. .--- -. ...- ... ..- -..- .--- 
.- -.. ..-. . ...- .- .-.. .-. -.-- --.. .... ..-. 
.. .-.. -..- -... -..- .-.. 
.-.. .-. .-- ..-. . .-- 
.- . -.- --.. . ... --.. ...- 
.-- .-. ..-. .... .-- .. -.-- 
-.- .- .-- .-- -.- .--- .. 
.-. ... .--- -... .--- ...- 
-.- .-- -.-- ..-. ... .--- -- .--- --.- - -.-- --.. .... ..-. 
.-- ... - -.-. -... .-.. . ..-. ... --.. .-.. .-.. 
.--- ..-. .-- -.- .- 
..-. .-- -- -.. 
--.. -.- --. .--- - --.- .-. .-- 
-.- .... .-. .- ...- -.- --.-   


R.W., S.T., R.F.         22.11.1963
```

Can you help me figure it out?

**EDIT**

My grandfather gave me some clues to help me figure it out.

Hint 1:

> 2 Men will help you decipher the message. First an 19th Century American from Charleston. Then a 16th Century Frenchman from Saint-Pourçain-sur-Sioule.

Hint 2:

> The Frenchman can find it quick once he figures out the *Hidden* Key

Hint 3:

> "If you want to *hide* something, do it in plain sight"

Hint 4:

> Sometimes you need to look on things *backwards*

Comment: My first guess was morse code.. but that just outputs this: XVVLEFSREAODNEYSJKWPVGJWJUXJWTDJNJNVSUXJADFEVALRYZHFILXBXLLRWFEWAEKZESZVWRFHWIYKAWWKJIRSJBJVKWYFSJMJQTYZHFWSTCBLEFSZLLJFWKAFWMDZKGJTQRWKHRAVKQ

Comment: @n_palum It certainly looks like morse code. I think we need to apply some kind of cipher...?

Comment: @Wen1now I have no idea what that cipher is so far.. The letters just look like initials and the numbers the date

Comment: Hello fellow puzzlers, I talked to my grandfather today and he said we are on a good track. Also he gave me some clues to help out.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! You may hold the hints for a while. Not everyone across the world has seen the puzzle yet. :)

Comment: @Techidiot thanks, I guess I should have waited a bit or give the hints one  at a time. I'm still new at this and will do better next time :)

Comment: @BojanB Wait so this is a true story?

Comment: @Wen1now No I made it up, to add something extra to the puzzle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first step to decode the message ...

> ... is clearly to convert the dots and dashes from Morse code:
>
>  XVVLEFSREAOD
>  NEYSJKWP
>  VGJWJUXJWTD
>  JNJNVSUXJ
>  ADFEVALRYZHF
>  ILXBXL
>  LRWFEW
>  AEKZESZV
>  WRFHWIY
>  KAWWKJI
>  RSJBJV
>  KWYFSJMJQTYZHF
>  WSTCBLEFSZLL
>  JFWKA
>  FWMD
>  ZKGJTQRW
>  KHRAVKQ

The generous hints tell us ...

> ... that we should apply a Vigenère cipher with a key hidden in plain sight and possibly read backwards. The ititials at the bottom read backwards are FRTSWR, which decodes the message to:
>
>  Sectionalism
>  Infantry
>  Confederacy
>  Surrender
>  Emancipation
>  Musket
>  Parole
>  Enfilade
>  Rampart
>  Theater
>  Yankee
>  Reconstruction
>  Abolitionist
>  North
>  Navy
>  Ironclad
>  Slavery

These words ...

> ... are related to the American Civil War.

The secret pass phrase is:

> [**SIC SEMPER TYRANNIS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic_semper_tyrannis)
>
>  It can be found by taking the first letter of each word. John Wilkes Booth claimed to have said it after shooting President Abraham Lincoln.

Comment: Great Job, with perfect explanation :)